# How to attach files via ASP.net application to FogBugz with C#

Tags: fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I have an ASP.net application that allows the users to report bugs and attach files. The bug together with its detail and attachments should be saved in FogBugz. 
I have managed to create everything except the file attachment part.

here is my code:

```
private void NewCaseWithFile()

    {
        string fbUrl = "https://test.fogbugz.com/api.asp";
        string fbToken = logInFogBugz();
        string param = "";


        param += "cmd=new";
        param += "&token=" + fbToken;


        param += "&sTags=" + "OnlineService,";
        param += "&sTitle=" + "Testing";

        param += "&sEvent=" + "This case is being created from Visual Studio";
        param += "&nFileCount=" + "1";
        param += "&File1=" + "Picture.png";


        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fbUrl + "?" + param);
        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";

        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = 0;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(streamReader);
    }
```

I have tried all instructions under "[Editing Cases](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/docs/70/topics/advanced/API.html)"  but it did not help. In fact I have no idea what are File 1, File 2 and how to send them to FogBugz.

Can anyone help me with this? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

File1 should be specified in the body of your multipart/form-data post (not as a querystring parameter).

You actually have to specify all the bytes in the file.

There's an answer on [fogbugz.stackexchange.com](http://fogbugz.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/how-do-i-upload-file-attachments-using-the-xml-api-in-net-c-or-vb-net) as well as a [C# FogBugz API wrapper](http://asp.net2.aspfaq.com/fogbugz-csharp-api-wrapper.html) that will handle all the parts for you.

The form parts in the body of your post would look like

```
--sdfjdsjsdflk SOME BOUNDARY--
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File1"; filename="foo.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/png

slfkajdflksjflajfdj
sldfjsd;aljfds
these are actual data bytes from the foo.jpg file
slfkjdsfljds
sdflajsdfs
```

Or you can look at [this question which points to an RFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238809/any-example-of-multipart-form-data) with an example.

Comment: While your link and sample is good and useful, your post seems a bit off.

Comment: Crappy comments system ;-)
While your link and sample is good and useful, your post seems a bit off.
Your form post specifies "base64" encoding; then you should also use it below. In this case the data would be:
c2xma2FqZGZsa3NqZmxhamZkag0Kc2xkZmpzZDthbGpmZHMNCnRoZXNlIGFyZSBhY3R1YWwgZGF0YSBieXRlcyBmcm9tIHRoZSBmb28uanBnIGZpbGUNCnNsZmtqZHNmbGpkcw0Kc2RmbGFqc2Rmcw==

That said I'm having problems with FogBugz ignoring the base64 flag and treating everything as binary. May be my bad ;-)