# asp.net web api controller return multipart form-data content

Tags: c#, asp.net, xamarin

All. Thanks in advance.
I have simple web api in c#. it returns data correctly now.
when I test it with postman, it returns "application/json". But when i consume it with modernhttpclient in xamarin, it tells me "multipart form data". 
Is anybody know how to fix it?
Is this api problem or xamarin problem?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238809/example-of-multipart-form-data

Comment: Content type is negotiated by request headers. This is useful to read about WebAPI: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation

Comment: hi, Greg, thanks for your reply.

Comment: --MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MSG"

duplicate
--MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="RESULT"

False
--MultipartDataMediaFormatterBoundary1q2w3e--

it is the result from .net web api. but post man shows me json.
Problem is response content type is multipart form data. but in post man, it is "application/json".

Comment: Show us the code please

Comment: [HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> GetResult(RequestModel model)
{

Comment: public Task<IHttpActionResult> GetResult(RequestModel model)
{
   ResponseModel model = new ResponseModel(){ID = 1, NAME="a"}
    return Ok(model);
}

Comment: My code is extremely easy one but response is Multipart-form data.