# Jersey handling multi-part upload asynchronously

Tags: java, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I have a file CRUD rest API where clients can upload files. These files can be as big as 1 GB.

What I want to do is to run some validation on other things (and possibly filename) before starting the upload. But Jersey's `FormDataMultiPart` waits for full upload before starting processing the request handler.

Maybe it's how HTTP works but if not, I want Jersey to hold the upload until I start reading from `InputStream`, saving a whole lot of effort and bandwidth. Is that possible?

Current code:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadFile(@NotNull FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart) {
    validateOtherThings(); // throws validation errors
    FormDataBodyPart formDataBodyPart = formDataMultiPart.getField("file");
    String filename = formDataBodyPart.getContentDisposition().getFileName();
    validateFilename(filename);
    InputStream inputStream = formDataBodyPart.getValueAs(InputStream.class);
    saveFile(filename, inputStream);
}
```

I have tried:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public void uploadFile(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    ...
    InputStream inputStream = request.getPart("file").getInputStream();
    ...
}
```

This actually goes into the method immediately but fails when doing `getPart("file")` with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No multipart config for servlet`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it is possible. Look at sample POST request with files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517227/158037 - Jersey needs to read whole request to know which fields are present before creating FormDataMultiPart object.
I guess it would be possible using Servlet (doPut()) and manually parse incoming data with something like https://github.com/synchronoss/nio-multipart but I doubt it is worth it. Just do the validation on client side, before sending and on server side, after receiving whole file.

Comment: "I don't know" is a comment, not an answer to the question.