# Sending files using pure HTTP request using telegram bot

Tags: telegram-bot

hello everyone I was tring to send files using my bot like `http://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendDocument?document=http://my_path&chat_id` but it ain't support .txt .docx..... and other formats..... any help please

Comment: What exactly do you mean under "pure HTTP"?

Comment: I mean without using any library

Comment: Without any library but still with some programming (if so depends on language) or pure HTTP i.e. web browser / something like postman?

Comment: Pure HTTP, I would like to know the basics (am asking this for learning purpose)..... to be more clear, am coding PHP and am using     file_get_contents("http://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/").... but I don't know what to put next in order to support all kinds of files

Comment: I have updated my answer with some code from existing telegram PHP library I use. There might be your answer

Answer (score 0):

According to https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sending-files

> Sending by URL In sendDocument, sending by URL will currently only
>   work for **gif**, **pdf** and **zip** files.

You may try to use this approach

> Post the file using multipart/form-data in the usual way that files
>   are uploaded via the browser. 10 MB max size for photos, 50 MB for
>   other files.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238809/example-of-multipart-form-data) might give you some ideas on how to do that.

### UPDATE

It is also good idea to use someone's library to understand how it works there.
For example, I use `longman/telegram-bot` from [this repo](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core). There is `encodeFile` method in [Request](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core/blob/master/src/Request.php) class.

Method is follows:

```
public static function encodeFile($file)
    {
        $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
        if ($fp === false) {
            throw new TelegramException('Cannot open "' . $file . '" for reading');
        }

        return $fp;
    }
```

Which means simple `fopen` method with `'rb'` parameter is enough to convert file.