# How to stream upload as multipart form data with fetch?

Tags: javascript, upload, fetch-api, multipartform-data, form-data

I am on chrome, where sending `ReadableStream` as an octet stream is [supported](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/fetch-streaming-requests#streaming-request-bodies). If I provide a `ReadableStream` as the `body` to `fetch`, everything works. However, if I `append` it to a `FormData` like below and provide that instead, that does not work.

```
async function main() {
  const blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(10 * 1024 * 1024)]);
  const body = new FormData();

  body.append("file", blob.stream());
 
  await fetch(..., {
    method: "POST"
    body: body,
    duplex: "half",
  });
}
```

This is because from [append documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append#examples):

> If the value is not a string or a Blob, `append()` will convert it to a string automatically:

So `file` in my form data gets coerced to the literal text `[object ...]`, not the actual binary data of the stream.

How can I stream `blob` using form data? **I must deal with `blob.stream()`**, since my use case requires a `ReadableStream`.

Comment: The only way I can see this working is by making the form data be part of the blob (not the blob part of the FormData, JSON document etc.). Maybe creating the content of the multipartform-data as a blob.

Comment: @chrwahl To make sure I understand right, you are thinking bypassing `FormData` entirely and assembling a blob per the multipart form data spec (so boundaries and all), which then has a `ReadableStream` created from it?

Comment: Yes, I guess that this package can turn a fordata object into multipart/form-data, but I was thinking more "low level", like constructing the content by hand -- something like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517227/322084 where you can see the structure of a POST request with the content-type of multipart/form-data.

Comment: "and assembling a blob per the multipart form data spec (so boundaries and all), which then has a ReadableStream created from it?". Yes, exactly. Would that work?

Comment: @chrwahl it's definitely a great idea, I'll give it a shot and see. Thank you!

Comment: @chrwahl It worked perfectly! As an optimization, I avoided the blob creation and created the readable stream from an async iterator instead (which yields the boundaries, headers and chunks of data), such that nothing is buffered. If you'd like to port over your comment to a quick answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: OK, I did an answer. Maybe you can extend the answer with some of your insights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see this working is by making the form data (either the plain value of the form fields or a FormData object) be part of the blob (not the blob part of the FormData, JSON document etc.). Maybe creating the content of the multipart/form-data as a blob.

Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517227/322084 where you can see the structure of a POST request with the content-type of multipart/form-data.