# Retrieve multiple images from web source with one http request for android app

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to build an android app and in that app I have a list view, which I would like to have thumbnail images in. The images are stored on a server, and they are all in the same folder (e.g. http://myserverlocation.com/images/dining/myImage1.jpg,myImage2.jpg, etc). What I want to know, is if there is an easy way to get all the images (approx 25) using ONE http request, or connection. What I want to avoid is making 25 http requests, one for each image, to get all the thumbnails. I'm familiar with AsyncTask, and BitMap, but I haven't seen anything on this site (or the internet) that talks about getting multiple images with one call. I was hoping someone here would have an answer for me, as to whether or not this is possible. I'm open to any suggestions on how I might be able to accomplish this task, without using all the phones resources and/or memory.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should a Multipart HTTP request with multiple files look like?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like)

Comment: No, that didn't answer my question. It was similar in content, but it didn't have anything regarding the code, or process. Thank you for the suggestion thought.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about exactly what your question is?  From this - "What I want to know, is if there is an easy way to get all the images (approx 25) using ONE http request, or connection." - I would say the answer is "have the server construct a multipart http response".  Then google "multipart http response" to learn more.  Does that set you on the right path, or are you asking something else?

Comment: I'm not looking to do anything server side. My hope is to be able to make one connection with the phone and with that connection get each of the files in the folder. If I can accomplish that with a multipart http request, then I'm all for it, but haven't seen anything that would suggest that I can.

Comment: Then I think you're out of luck.  If the server is expecting one HTTP request per file, I don't think the client can send one HTTP request for multiple files, have the server automatically send all of the files back in one HTTP response.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Thank you for your help. Do you know of anything else that might help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you are controlling the web service, I would highly recommended storing a zip file and retrieving that. I believe that Android likes to play with bzip, but that may be wrong.
Either way, I remember reading on the Android Dev site or watching a Google IO talk and they suggested to zip it before you ship it.

Comment: That may be an option, but the app I am building is essentially a framework for other apps, with different content. All the apps have the data stored as XML on the server, and the image is just a path. I would like to build something that I can reuse for other apps that have the same format.