# Making a POST request to external API with multipart form data in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express, multipartform-data

I am developing an app for a course and I am having trouble getting photo upload to work.  I didn't have much trouble with other endpoints, but this particular one has me stuck for a week now.  Below I have copied the part I have issue with from the iNaturalist [API reference](http://www.inaturalist.org/pages/api+reference).

> **POST /observation_photos**
>
> > > *Auth required.*
> > >       Add photos to observations. This is only for iNat-hosted photos. For adding photos hosted on other services, see POST /observations and PUT /observations/:id.
> > >
> > > **Params**
> > >
> > > **observation_photo[observation_id]**
> > >       ID of the observation receiving this photo.
> > >       Allowed values: Valid iNat observation ID
> > >       
> > >       **file**
> > >       The photo data.
> > >       Allowed values: Multipart photo data

On the front end, I have this form.  I made sure I only uploading .png images.

```
 form(role='form', method='post', enctype='multipart/form-data')
   div.form-group
     input.form-control#image(type='file', accept='png', name='file')
   button.btn.btn-default(type='submit') Submit
```

Here is an excerpt of my code in the attempt to do a POST request following the API instructions.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
var multipartMiddleware = multipart();

router.post('/playground', multipartMiddleware, function(req,res){
    client = new Client();

    var args = {
        parameters:{'observation_photo[observation_id]': '1055033', //id for a record
                    'file' : req.files.file},
        headers:{'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
    }

    client.post('https://inaturalist.org/observation_photos',args, function(data,response){
        console.log(response.body);
        res.send(data);
    });
}
```

I guess the confusion I have is the file parameter and what form the POST endpoint is expecting for that parameter.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the response you're getting from iNat? You also need to make sure that the request you're making to iNat is a [multipart request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request). If you're using https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client I'm not sure if it supports that, but it looks like https://github.com/danwrong/restler does.

Comment: yes it finally worked.  Thank you. Probably should found this solution myself but glad I can move on now.