# how to read a file on client machine using the folder location

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, multipart

This was jsp file uploading form

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>File Uploading form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="./read.do" method="post">
        Select the file to read: <input type="file" id="myFile" size="50">
        <br />
         path is: <input type="text" name="path" />

        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Copy path</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myFile").value;
     document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[3].setAttribute("value",x); 

}
</script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i was not uploading the file to my server i was just taking the path of the file and reading the file using following code in servlet

```
String path = req.getParameter("path");
            FileInputStream fis = null;
            File excel = new File(path);
            fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
```

this works fine when i run on same machine where server is present .But when i try to access from other machine the code is searching the path in my machine but not on client machin how to over come this.
               I have seen some other ways like using multipart but there the file is loading to server but for my requirement i should not upload the file directly to my server i have to read the complete file on client machine it self by taking the file path . Please suggest me some ideas to attain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File upload is a [multi-part request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request). request.getParameter() returns the file path on the client machine.  Instead of that, you need to use either [request.getPart()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPart(java.lang.String))  method or libraries like [apache-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) to retrieve the inputstream of the remote file.

Answer (score 2):

You can try JavaScript File Reader API for reading the file contents in the client side using JS.
[file API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/)

Ex:

```html
var file = document.getElementById("fileForUpload").files[0];
if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = evt.target.result;
    }
    reader.onerror = function (evt) {
        document.getElementById("fileContents").innerHTML = "error reading file";
    }
}
```

or you can also go for HTML5 's file Reader [HTML5 FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)