# How to upload CSV file to the database using Spring Hibernate MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc, csv

Can someone please explain "How to upload CSV file to the database using Spring Hibernate MVC?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your client should create a [multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request).

> A HTTP multipart request is a HTTP request that HTTP clients construct
>   to send files and data over to a HTTP Server.

The Spring MVC handler method that handles such a request in its simplest form would look something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value="fileupload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void processUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        // process your file
}
```

the client side depends on your needs (and your client), here's an example made using the html form

```
<form id="fileuploadForm" action="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">File</label>
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
    <p><button type="submit">Upload</button></p>        
</form>
```

The following tutorial gives you a more detailed insight http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-file-upload.jsp