# Upload image post request over http to other application using Paperclip

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am able to upload image attachements using paperclip to my application. But I would like to send the image to another application via faraday connection. Other attributes are successfully sent but not the attachment image. I am not sure what I should do to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an HTTP library that can create Multipart Post requests.

For example Typhoeus can do file uploads: https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#handling-file-uploads.

There's also Net::HTTP Multipart Post: https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post

And finally: https://github.com/jwagener/httmultiparty

Read the READMEs to any of those gems, they all make it equally easy to do file uploads. I like Typhoeus because it can do parallel requests. The other two are a bit simpler but equally useful.

Learn more about what a multipart form post is:

- [What is http multipart request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)
- [application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data)
- http://www.huyng.com/posts/under-the-hood-an-http-request-with-multipartform-data/

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer @diego.greyrobot. Coud you also give me idea how to make a get request to the other application and then be able to get paperclip attachment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I have to stick with using faraday, here is how to achieve the posting of paperclip attachments.

```
    Faraday.new(:url => url) do |faraday|
        faraday.request :multipart
    end
```

And put the attachement as such in where post request happens

```
params['avatar'] = Faraday::UploadIO.new(avatar.map.path, 'image/jpeg')
```