# How to request Paperclip attachment via faraday connection over http

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, faraday

I am making a get request via http to my other application. Both apps use Paperclip to manage attachment. How can I achieve to make the target app make a correct response with the attachment? Or any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to serve same asset from two different applications. that's a bad idea because it will lead to sync issus & race conditions.

Instead, you should create a image service which runs on images.example.com. Here you will expose an endpoint where images can be uploaded via HTTP POST and download via URL.

Now, get both of your applications to upload & download images from this service.

Comment: Thanks but I am trying to upload an image which I am able to do using standard multipart post with faraday exposing the attachment. I did that here ==> http://stackoverflow.com/a/29862922/3616241
I would like to now get the image and be able to use to my application not share the same asset as you mentioned