# What is Rack::Utils.multipart_part_limit within Rails and what function does it perform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, multipart

Rack::Utils.multipart_part_limit is set to 128 by default.

What purpose does the value have and what effect does it have within the Rails system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telling it short, this value limits the amount of simultaneously opened files for multipart requests.
To understand better what is multipart, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request) question.

The reason for this limitation is an ability to better adjust your app for your server. If you have too many files opened at a time, your system can run out of handles. If you are not worried of this you can set this value to 0 in your initializer like this `Rack::Utils.multipart_part_limit = 0`