# Is use of Commons FileUpload to handle multipart/form-data not deprecated?

Tags: java, servlets, file-upload

I just start learning Java EE and now I try to implement to my learning project uploading files from HTML forms.

Many tutorials use to handle file uploads in Servlets by use of Commons FileUpload API. But Java 6 introduced the multipart configuration option into Servlet 3.0.  Is it mean that use of Commons FileUpload is deprecated and all  those tutorials are out of date?

EDIT:
@Vishal answered FileUpload API is different way to handle same task.

My question now is, what advantages has one API over another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No its not Deprecated, Else you can say a different way to upload and send MIME. 
Commons FileUpload API is provided by Apache foundation and Multipart is feature provided from Java 6, so there is no way to link this two things and deprecating FileUpload API. I hope this clears at least few of your doubts.

For more details refer this links [FileUpload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)
and [Multipart Utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)

Comment: What are advantages of one API over another one then?

Comment: for me its always better to use Java provided features instead of including any other external API jar file.  :)  for more details discussion on multi part check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request