# How to add HTTPBody in NSMutableURLRequest in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios10, nsmutableurlrequest

I am passing HTTPBody in my request. But its unable to get proper response.

below is my code :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://sample.ios.com/l1/voucher"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"text/html; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Now pass your own parameter --------

[request setValue:@"g064a4b5aa95556a7b0b4435d94c317840e9b456" forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"123651236512" forHTTPHeaderField:@"uuid"];
[request setValue:@"myIphone" forHTTPHeaderField:@"devicename"];


NSString *myRequestString =@"voucher=JHAHSDGH-80";
NSLog(@"%@",myRequestString);
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
[ request setHTTPBody: myRequestData ];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[responseData bytes]];
NSLog(@"content : %@",content);
```

Output is coming like below :

```
content : {"voucher":["The voucher field is required."]}
```

So how can I set HTTPBody ?

Please help me.

Comment: can you show ur URL and Params , '

Comment: devicename , uuid is this parameter ?

Comment: original URL i can't show but its working on postman , but thorugh coding m not getting

Comment: @KKRocks : Yes devicename, uuid, X-Authorization are 3 parameter

Comment: and voucher=JHAHSDGH-80 is parameter or header ?

Comment: Voucher is a body. I have to send voucher as key and code as a value to this request. How to add the http body

Comment: If you want to send a _MIME-Multipart Request_, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPBody is set to be as NSData, Which is the type of NSJSONSerialization class.

So your solution would be, make an NSArray and embedded into NSDictionary class as your web services required.

Then use **[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:'Your dictionary' options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error]** To convert a JSON into **Data** And it will return a NSData class obj.

Then you add to your request as,
[request setHTTPBody: Data]

Hope this will help you. Let me know if I got your question wrongly.

Comment: @SRNayak : What is your HTTPBody need to feed?

Comment: NSArray * name = @[a, b, c]

NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:@[name,@“hello",] forKeys:@[@"firstName",@"message"]];

 NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dictionary  
options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil]
                
[requestToPostDataField setHTTPBody:data];

Try this method.

Comment: My body will be voucher= GSJWBJEB-90

Comment: NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObject:@[] forKeys:@[@"firstName",@"message"]]; NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] [requestToPostDataField setHTTPBody:data]

Comment: NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObject:@[@"voucher"] forKey:@[@"GSJWBJEB-9"]]; NSData *data=[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject: dictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] [requestToPostDataField setHTTPBody:data] Try this one

Comment: same issue "content : {"voucher":["The voucher field is required."]}" is coming

Comment: NSDictionary * dic = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"GSJWBJEB-90",@"voucher", nil];
    NSData * data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]);

Comment: Output: {
    voucher = "GSJWBJEB-90";
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128155/discussion-between-s-r-nayak-and-deepak-kumar-sahu).