# unable to add image binary into multipart/form-data

Tags: python, python-3.x, multipartform-data

I received an error: expected str instance, bytes found when i tried to add image binary into multipart/form-data.

The problem is i tried to append the imageData in binary format to strings. Is there a way to add binary image to multipart/form data?

I'm at my wits end, would appreciate some help for this.

```
imageData = request.FILES['filePath'].read()


content_type, request_body = encode_multipart_formdata([('include_target_data', targetMetaDataRet),
                                                     ('max_num_results', str(maxNoResultRet))],
                                                     [('image', imagePath, imageData)])

def encode_multipart_formdata(fields, files):

    BOUNDARY = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
    CRLF = '\r\n'
    lines = []
    for (key, value) in fields:
        lines.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        lines.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"' % key)
        lines.append('')
        lines.append(value)
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
        lines.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
        lines.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
        lines.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
        lines.append('')
        lines.append(value)
    lines.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
    lines.append('')
    body = CRLF.join(lines)
    content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=%s' % BOUNDARY
    return content_type, body
```

**Traceback:**

```
  35.            response = get_response(request)

  128.           response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

  126.           response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

  166.           [('image', imagePath, imageData)])

  232.           body = CRLF.join(lines)

Exception Type: TypeError at /identify_shrine
Exception Value: sequence item 12: expected str instance, bytes found
```

**as per @coltoneakins request I modified request body to bytes, but I seem to be getting a bad request error any idea why?**

**Code:**

```
content_type = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$'
request_body = '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$' +  '\n'+'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="include_target_data"' + '\n' + '\n' + 'top'+ '\n' + '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$' +'\n' + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="max_num_results"' + '\n' + '\n' + '1' + '\n' + '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$' +'\n' + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="img_2.jpg"' + '\n' + 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' + '\n' + '\n'
request_body1 = request_body.encode('utf-8')
request_body2 = imageData
request_body3 = ('\n' + '\n' + '----------ThIs_Is_tHe_bouNdaRY_$').encode('utf-8')
request_body4 = request_body1 + request_body2 + request_body3

content_type_bare = 'multipart/form-data'

# Sign the request and get the Authorization header
# use client key
auth_header = authorization_header_for_request(CLIENT_ACCESS_KEY, CLIENT_SECRET_KEY, HTTP_METHOD, request_body4,
                                               content_type_bare,
                                               date, path)

request_headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': auth_header,
    'Content-Type': content_type,
    'Date': date
}
try:
    # Make the request over HTTPS on port 443
    connection = http.client.HTTPSConnection(CLOUD_RECO_API_ENDPOINT, 443)
    connection.request(HTTP_METHOD, path, request_body4, request_headers)

    response = connection.getresponse()
    response_body = response.read()
    reason = response.reason
    status = response.status

finally:
    connection.close()
```

Comment: Can you post the error traceback (with offending line) ?

Comment: @SamuelDion-Girardeau thanks for your reply, added the traceback :-)

Comment: Note: you could make your life so much easier by using the `requests` library for this task, which will do the multipart encoding for you. Failing that, you can use the `email.mime` package (part of the standard library) to ecode multipart/formdata output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a type issue in your code. You are getting a **TypeError expected str instance, bytes found** because you are attempting to **join()** a list that contains both **str** types and **bytes** types in Python.

Look at these lines in your code:

```py
    for (key, filename, value) in files:
    lines.append('--' + BOUNDARY)
    lines.append('Content-Disposition: form-data; name="%s"; filename="%s"' % (key, filename))
    lines.append('Content-Type: %s' % get_content_type(filename))
    lines.append('')
    lines.append(value) # <---------- THIS IS BYTES, EVERYTHING ELSE IS STR
lines.append('--' + BOUNDARY + '--')
lines.append('')
body = CRLF.join(lines) # <---------- AHHH RED FLAG!!!
```

**CRLF** is type **str**. But, **value** (which is added on to your **lines** list) is **bytes**. This means you end up with **lines** containing both **str** and **bytes** types. When you are sending an image via the mulitpart/form-data request, the whole body of the request is bytes. So, you need to use join() with only **bytes** types.

This is what you are doing:

```py
body = CRLF.join(lines)
```

which is really:

```py
'\r\n, i am a str'.join(['i am also str', b'I am not a str, I am bytes']) # <-- NO
```

This is what you need to be doing:

```py
b'I am bytes'.join([b'I am also bytes', b'Me too!'])
```

Also, just so that you are aware, the Requests library provides mechanisms for you to send files. See the [files parameter in the Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.0.0/api/) or this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12385661/9347694

So, you may not need to reinvent the wheel here. Requests will multipart encode the file and construct the request for you.

Comment: if I convert the whole request body to bytes, do the request header and accept, authorisation, date need to be in bytes as well?

Comment: Hi, I made changes to my code, need your assistance, thanks!

Comment: Good question. The short answer is no. The Requests library does not do this, for example. Also, if you use the 'Network' panel in a web browser like Firefox, you can see how requests are formed when you upload a file to like an image sharing site. The headers are not binary data when you deal with them. But, the body is. If you would like to learn more about how this works, read into UTF-8 character encoding and binary.

Comment: Hi, i stupidly made the request header bytes, I made the changes to text, but I'm still getting a bad request error, any idea?

Comment: See: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html . Also, I don't think you are ending your lines with CRLF's--'\n' is not the same as '\r\n'. To better troubleshoot what is wrong, we should look at the request body that your code is forming. Then, compare it to the proper format for a multipart/form request body. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712083/9347694

Comment: thanks for your help, btw the https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html you posted is super duper useful, i realise my boundary formatting is wrong all along thanks so much