# How to change content type of an http request correctly in Java?

Tags: java, request

I have this code to upload an attachment with the servicenow API:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

                  //Add needed headers
                  Header header = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                  Header header2 = new BasicHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json");
                  List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
                  headers.add(header);
                  headers.add(header2);

                  //Add credential
              CredentialsProvider provider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                  UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials     = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("yourUserName", "yourPassword");
                  provider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, credentials);
                  CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                                                                          .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(provider)
                                                                          .setDefaultHeaders(headers)
                                                                          .build();

                  HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://yourInstanceName/api/now/attachment/file?table_name=incident&table_sys_id=c8c3ba6643333a4073a1433e0210c706&file_name=Tulips.jpg");
                  String textFileName = "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/Tulips.jpg";
                  byte[] fileBytes = getBytes(textFileName);
                  post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(fileBytes));
                  ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
                  String responseBody = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
                  System.out.println(responseBody);
            } catch (Exception e) {

  e.printStackTrace();

}
  }

  private static byte[] getBytes(String filepath) throws Exception{
                  File file = new File(filepath);
                  //init array with file length
                  byte[] bytesArray = new byte[(int) file.length()];

                  FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                  fis.read(bytesArray); //read file into bytes[]
                  fis.close();

                  return bytesArray;
          }
```

This works like it should but when I try to upload a csv file it doesn't work.

I changed the file with a csv, changed the filename in the url and changed the content type to "text/csv".

What should I change to make this work?

Comment: It doesn't work as it is, not for jpeg nor for anything. You were merely led to believe it might work, because sometimes it will arbitrarily do the things needed. But the code is in no way correct. A correct code would do the things needed *always*, not *arbitrarily by chance*. Your getBytes() method doesn't read all the bytes of the files. A jpeg may be okay with this and be a little corrupted. Most file formats will be broken beyond repair.

Comment: Can you help me and put me on a good way to make it correct? Can I use IOUtils.toByteArray instead of the read?

Comment: Trying. I need to make a full response for that, and if I make a full response I must check the rest of your code does what it's supposed to. Will need some time. In the meantime, you'd be wise to check how to read a binary file.

Comment: I edited my comment.

Comment: IOUtils.toByteArray would be fine. But so would Java's native Files.readAllBytes(). IOUtils were made for outdated versions of Java.

Comment: I updated that part. Still getting a bad request when I change the content type ( text/csv ) and file for a csv. No issues with an image and/or json files.

Comment: Then I guess that wasn't the only problem. I'll have to check this web API to get an idea what it doesn't like

Comment: https://docs.servicenow.com/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_AttachmentAPI-POST.html <== This is the API I am using

Comment: On Postman I get a 200 status code: OK. This is weird.

Answer (score -1):

Your request have another content type if you want to upload files, so you have to use a multipart request. See [What is http multipart request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)

Comment: Not at all. We're in the time of REST APIs, the way browsers used to work is getting outdated.