# when uploading file with HTTP Post, how are contents of file sent?

Tags: http, post, postman, multipartform-data

I'm testing HTTP POST file upload with postman, with 2 text parameters and 1 file parameter.

I could get raw request body, but I want to know what exactly the content of file is. Is it sent as base64? or as text stream?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [ask] and use search to see if your question has already been answered ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request )  and several others at SO,  "http form multipart" in Google.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is http multipart request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does HTTP file upload work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659808/how-does-http-file-upload-work)