# Change environment live in Angular / Ionic app at runtime

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a ionic/angular app. I don't want to release 2 apps : dev and prod but to release only one and the user can switch from the user interface between dev and prod.

It will be "easy" if I put all my credentials and values in my own files and variables but it will be cleaner to use the provided angular environment system.

So I have those 2 files :
environments/environment.ts
environments/environment.prod.ts

I understand how to build or run the app in prod or dev/test, but is there a way the user can change the environment in the same app (not by building 2 apps). So is dynamical reloading values of environment.ts or environment.prod.ts possible? If the app restart it's not a big deal.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you also have the possibility that there is code in active development that would be pushed to the development environment to be tested and not (yet) to production? In your description that would not be possible.

Comment: There are similar questions on [so] like this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/64588578/1260204. You will have better luck if you just search for switching environments in angular (leave off the live/release/dev keywords).