# Flutter/Dart: How upload binary file to Dropbox?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, http, dropbox

I'm trying to upload a binary file to Dropbox using https://github.com/dart-lang/http. Following https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_upload, my code is:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Map<String,String> headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
  'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
  'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path": "/file", "mode": "overwrite"}',
};

final resp = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload"),
    body: "--data-binary @\'/my/binary/file\'",
    headers: headers);
```

`file` gets uploaded, but unfortunately this only contains the text `--data-binary @'/my/binary/file'` (i.e. not the actual file).

**Am I missing something/doing something incorrectly?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending binary data directly as the body worked:

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final file = File('/my/binary/file');
Uint8List data = await file.readAsBytes();

Map<String,String> headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer MY_TOKEN',
    'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path": "/file", "mode": "overwrite"}',
};

final resp = await http.post(
    Uri.parse("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload"),
    body: data,
    headers: headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass

```
body: "--data-binary @\'/my/binary/file\'",
```

as the body of your POST request, exactly this is the data to get send to the server. The body is raw data, that just gets passed along to the server and in no way interpreted by dart.

Have a look at Dart's [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html). Or for general information:[SO on multipart requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request).