# Do you know what´s the difference between connect-multiparty, formidable and file-upload? How do they work?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, express

Hello i have to explain the difference between connect-multiparty, formidable and express-fileupload and i would like to know your opinions, which is the most recommended to use in an ecommerce mean stack project?

Which do you like to use more for uploading files in nodeJS environment whit mongoDB and express?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow community! Please read this (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking. And also provide more detailed information about your question.

Comment: Here is a same question like yours:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40099016/difference-between-multer-multiparty-and-connect-multiparty-nodejs/40830794

Comment: Thanks @AlexZeDim i will read it right away

Comment: Thanks @pr1ax i will check it