# Most appropriate Content-Type for my case

Tags: rest, http, content-type

I am just looking for the most appropriate way to indicate with HTTP POST my content type.

I have csv files. They may have 1 line or they may have multiple lines. As I am implementing the server side of this, distinguishing between the two can make my implementation a bit cleaner.

```
text/cms+csv
```

Is what I have but that doesn't indicate how many entities exist in the payload. Do I use a custom param?

Comment: Please don't make up media types. Use a registered one.

Answer (score 2):

There is no requirement to indicate the number of entities in a request payload.
If you are uploading multiple files in a single request, then each file in that request will have a corresponding entity. Each entity in the request would then include its content-type, etc. This StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like) shows an example.

If I understand your case correctly, you are uploading a single csv which may or may not have multiple lines. There is no header that describes this. The closest header to your case is arguably the Content-Length header. This header indicates the size of an entity body.

To answer your question more directly, if you *really need* the line count, you might create a custom header. And as for an appropriate Content-Type, you should consider `text/csv`.