# Multipart Request and Custom Header

Tags: java, file-upload, apache-commons

For my current solution, I'm using apache commons FileUpload library to process incoming multi-part requests. I'm able to send the files appropriately then read the stream on the server end using the streaming api code [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/streaming.html).

If you look at the format of multipart requests listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like), there is a Content-Disposition listed for each file added. I need to add a *startByte* tag (similar to how you add a "filename" tag in content-disposition). I'm not too sure how to do that properly and then retrieve it in the request? This is of course not a global header, because multiple files are in this stream.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for anyone who might be interested, and turns out was easy: To do this, on the client, you append the header like below:

```
 outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + filename + "\"; filename=\"" + filename + "\";\r\n");
 outputStream.writeBytes("My-Custom-Header: My-Data\r\n");
 outputStream.writeBytes("\r\n");
```

Then, on the server, using commons FileUpload, you would just do:

```
FileItemHeaders headers = item.getHeaders();
headers.getHeader("My-Custom-Header");
```