# C# how to handle multipart file uploaded from android to C#

Tags: c#, rest, networking

I'm uploading excel file from android to C# the request from android is arriving to c# server(I don't want to use asp.net).

I've built from scratch a simple HTTPServe, I do't how to handle multipart data upload in c# that's my code :

Request.cs:

```
  class Request
{

    public String type { get; set; }
    public String url { get; set; }

    public String host { get; set; }

    private Request(String type,String url,String host)
    {
        this.type = type;

        this.url = url;

        this.host = host;
    }


    public static Request GetRequest(String request)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
            return null;

        String[] tokens = request.Split(' ');      

        String type = tokens[0];

        String url = tokens[1];

        String host = tokens[4];




        return new Request(type, url, host);



    }
}
```

Response.cs:
    class Response
    {

```
    private Byte[] data = null;

    private String status;

    private String mime;


    private Response(String status,String mime,Byte[] data)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.mime = mime;

    }


    public static Response From(Request request)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(request.type);
        if (request == null)
            return MakeNullRequest();



        if (request.type.Equals("POST"))
        {
            return UploadCompleteResponse(request);

        }

        return MakeFromExcel();

    }




    private static Response UploadCompleteResponse(Request request)
    {   //Handling the multipart request here but I don't know how that is a simple example 
        Console.WriteLine("uploaded!!");
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("uploaded!!");

        return new Response("ok 200","text/plain",bytes);


    }



    //private static Response MakeFromFile(FileInfo f)
    //{
    //  // to do later 
    //    //return new Response("200 ok", "text/html", d);
    //}



    //Retruning an excel file response  
    private static Response MakeFromExcel()
    {
        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + HTTPServer.EXCEL_DIR+"brains.xlsx";
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            FileStream fs = info.OpenRead();
            BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
            read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
            fs.Close();
            return new Response("200 ok", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", d);
        }

        return PageNotFound();


    }

    private static Response MakeNullRequest()
    {

        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory+HTTPServer.MSG_DIR +"400.html";
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        FileStream fs=info.OpenRead();
        BinaryReader read=new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
        read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);

        fs.Close();
        return new Response("400 Bad Request", "text/html", d);
    }


    private static Response PageNotFound()
    {

        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + HTTPServer.MSG_DIR + "400.html";
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        FileStream fs = info.OpenRead();
        BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
        read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
        return new Response("404 Not Found", "text/html", d);
    }

    public void Post(NetworkStream stream)
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}\r\nServer: {2}\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\nAccept-Ranges: 255 bytes\r\nContent-Length: {4}\r\n", HTTPServer.VERSION
            , status, HTTPServer.NAME, mime, data.Length));
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Flush();
        stream.Close();

    }
}
```

In the above code I used more than one type of response You can access and the request fields by increasing the size of the token array.

HTTServer.cs:

```
    class HTTPServer
{
    public const String MSG_DIR = "\\root\\msg\\";
    public const String EXCEL_DIR = "\\root\\excel\\";
    public const String WEB_DIR = "\\root\\web\\";
    public const String VERSION = "HTTP/1.1";
    public const String NAME = "Thecode007 HTTP SERVER v 1.0";
    private bool running = false;

    private TcpListener listener;



    public HTTPServer(int port)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,port);
    }


    public void Start() {

        Thread serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));

        serverThread.Start();

    }


    private void Run()
    {

        running = true;

        listener.Start();

        while (running)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();

            HandleClient(client);

              Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");





        }

        running = false;

         listener.Stop();
    }

    private void HandleClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

        String msg = "";

        while (reader.Peek() != -1)
        {

            msg += reader.ReadLine()+"\n";

        }



        Console.WriteLine(msg);


        Request req = Request.GetRequest(msg);

        Response resp = Response.From(req);


        resp.Post(client.GetStream());
    }



}
```

And here is the main method:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Starting Serving on port 9000");

        HTTPServer server = new HTTPServer(9000);

        server.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Download and install the Ace provider for .net. It has an Excel extension. There are many examples around to read an Excel file through ADO.net. Once you have a datatable you will be all set.

Comment: I don't need an ace provider, I just need to know how handle multipart data of any file and save it on disk it is a core networking thing..I want to know how to handle it instead of using some framework...I want to save that excel not read it so ado .net do nothing.

Comment: Sorry I bothered you. I hate to tell you, but you are using "some framework".

Comment: You didn't get me...Ado is not a networkibg core feature to handle post get multipart upload download request it is database stuf...I need  use plaun c# without using a framework ie 3rd party libraries..

Comment: C# is built on the .Net framework. I mentioned no 3rd party libraries. Again, sorry I bothered you.

Comment: Okay I'm kinda new to c#...But how ADO will help me to handle those requests?

Answer (score 2):

#### Disclaimer: You should never write a HTTP server directly with TcpClient for any production work. There are far too many specifications to be accounted for and C# has these built in to any Asp.Net web server you use.

That being said, for an exercise this is a matter of parsing the request in a specific way. You should be able to reference these questions to learn more about the details of multipart boundary:

- [What is http multipart request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958448/what-is-http-multipart-request)
- [What should a Multipart HTTP request with multiple files look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like)

Essentially, you will have to read a header from the http headers (`Content-Type`), and parse the value of `boundary=` to determine what is separating the key/value pairs of the multipart form in the request body. Once you've got the boundary you will have to parse the body of the request into the real key/value pairs of the form. From there, the contents of the uploaded file will be the value of whatever key the form submits it as.

[Read more on the official W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart/form-data-encoding-algorithm)

Comment: I know how it looks like but I don't how to handle it???,how to fetch the post data ??..I've already handles it in java but in C# it is unknown to me  cause I new to it..

Comment: @NeilThank you my response on my client was not compatible with text/plain response of my server so the session is closed just after the first partition and that is why it was closing the connection...

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Response.cs:

```
 class Response
   {

    private Byte[] data = null;

    private String status;

    private String mime;


    private Response(String status,String mime,Byte[] data)
    {
        this.status = status;
        this.data = data;
        this.mime = mime;

    }


    public static Response From(Request request)
    {


        if (request == null)
            return MakeNullRequest();



        if (request.type.Equals("POST"))
        {
            return UploadCompleteResponse(request);

        }

        return MakeFromExcel();

    }




    private static Response UploadCompleteResponse(Request request)
    {  //I added on the rquest array the datapart which contains data
       String data=request.data;


        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("uploaded!!");

        return new Response("ok 200","text/plain",bytes);


    }



    //private static Response MakeFromFile(FileInfo f)
    //{
    //  // to do later 
    //    //return new Response("200 ok", "text/html", d);
    //}



    //Retruning an excel file response  
    private static Response MakeFromExcel()
    {
        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + HTTPServer.EXCEL_DIR+"brains.xlsx";
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            FileStream fs = info.OpenRead();
            BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
            read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
            fs.Close();
            return new Response("200 ok", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", d);
        }

        return PageNotFound();


    }

    private static Response MakeNullRequest()
    {

        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory+HTTPServer.MSG_DIR +"400.html";
        Console.WriteLine(file);
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        FileStream fs=info.OpenRead();
        BinaryReader read=new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
        read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);

        fs.Close();
        return new Response("400 Bad Request", "text/html", d);
    }


    private static Response PageNotFound()
    {

        String file = Environment.CurrentDirectory + HTTPServer.MSG_DIR + "400.html";
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
        FileStream fs = info.OpenRead();
        BinaryReader read = new BinaryReader(fs);
        Byte[] d = new Byte[fs.Length];
        read.Read(d, 0, d.Length);
        return new Response("404 Not Found", "text/html", d);
    }

    public void Post(NetworkStream stream)
    {

        try
        {
               StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1}\r\nServer: {2}\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\nAccept-Ranges: 255 bytes\r\nContent-Length: {4}\r\n", HTTPServer.VERSION
            , status, HTTPServer.NAME, mime, data.Length));
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Flush();

        stream.Close();

        }catch(Exception  ex){


        }




    }
}
```

Request.cs:

```
    class Request
{

    public String type { get; set; }
    public String url { get; set; }

    public String host { get; set; }


    public String data { get; set; }




    private Request(String type,String url,String host)
    {
        this.type = type;

        this.url = url;

        this.host = host;
    }

    private Request(String type, String url, String host,String data)
    {
        this.type = type;

        this.url = url;

        this.host = host;

        this.data = data;
    }


    public static Request GetRequest(String request)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(request))
            return null;

        String[] tokens = request.Split(' ');      

        String type = tokens[0];

        String url = tokens[1];

        String host = tokens[4];
        String data = "N/A";
        if (tokens.Length >= 9)
        {
            data = tokens[8];



        }

        return new Request(type, url, host, data);



    }
}
```

Secondly my android client was excpecting a response which is responsbody type not a plain text thats why the data was never sent....