# How to send multipart/form-data with Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, http, web

I want to send a `POST` request to a rest endpoint. the rest endpoint [documentation](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/nodes/createNode) says:

> Create a node and add it as a primary child of node nodeId.
>
> This endpoint supports both JSON and multipart/form-data (file
>   upload).
>
> Using multipart/form-data
>
> Use the filedata field to represent the content to upload, for
>   example, the following curl command will create a node with the
>   contents of test.txt in the test user's home folder.
>
> curl -utest:test -X POST
>   host:port/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/-my-/children
>   -F filedata=@test.txt
>
> You can use the name field to give an alternative name for the new
>   file.
>
> You can use the nodeType field to create a specific type. The default
>   is cm:content

I managed to send a correct request to this endpoint by the following code:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> postNode(String nodeId, byte[] content) {
  MultiValueMap<String, Object> bodyMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
ByteArrayResource contentsAsResource = new ByteArrayResource(content) {
    @Override
    public String getFilename() {
        return "name22222";
    }
};

  bodyMap.add("filedata", contentsAsResource);

  ///bodyMap.add("filedata", content);// why this does not work??!

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(bodyMap, headers);
        return restTemplate.exchange("/nodes/{nodeId}/children", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, byte[].class, nodeId);
}
```

but I have two questions:

1 - why the commented line does not work?

2 - the docs says :

> You can use the name field to give an alternative name for the new
>   file.

I did not use a `"name"` field, but the server saved my files with the correct name(=`"name22222"`), why?(I thought `multipart/form-data` is a kind of a simple name-value, if this is correct then I have a field named "filedata" and its value is my `byte` array content, so how the file name is send?).  and how can I specify the file name with a **field**?

update :
i think i found my answers. i just need to read about `multipart/form-data`!

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913626/what-should-a-multipart-http-request-with-multiple-files-look-like usefull

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this example will be useful to find out how you can upload one or more files using Spring.

```java
     byte[] fileContent = "testFileContent".getBytes();
     String filename = "testFile.xml";

     MultiValueMap<String, String> fileMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
     ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition
         .builder("form-data")
         .name("file")
         .filename(filename)
         .build();

     fileMap.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString());
     HttpEntity<byte[]> fileEntity = new HttpEntity<>(fileContent, fileMap);

     MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
     body.add("file", fileEntity);

     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

     HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);

     ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
         .postForEntity("/import/file, requestEntity, String.class);
```