# How to upload multiple files using rest-client in vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, rest-client

I have a post API call, which allows me to upload multiple images within form-data parameter in Postman. As you can see below, I'm sending multiple images having the key `images`

[image]

I wanna implement the same thing using the extension [rest-client](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=humao.rest-client) in vscode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/913749/6530134 probably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Tomothy G.'s comment I found the solution, it looks like this:

```
### ---------------------------- UPLOAD FEED IMAGES ----------------------------
POST {{hostname}}/upload_feed_images
Authorization: {{token}}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary

--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="my_image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

< /Users/anel-bou/Desktop/my_image.jpg
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="images"; filename="my_image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

< /Users/anel-bou/Desktop/my_image.jpg
--boundary--
### -------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

the parameter `name="images"` stands for the key that the files should belong to